# I have a problem while executing the selenium script, it takes longer time to perform its Manuel testing

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-rc

For example this statement takes 41 second to perform the Manuel testing:

```
try:
        print("at2-click" + " - Time used=%ss" % int((time.time() - start_time)))
        time.sleep(2)
        wait_until_visible_then_click(element_by_id)
        men_10 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="product-transaction-area"]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/a[10]')))
        men_10.click()
    except exp.NoSuchElementException as e:
        no_such_element_exption('at2', str(e))
    time.sleep(3)
```

but this statement takes 160 seconds to perform its Manuel testing

```
try:
        print("In den Wb2 product" + " - Time used=%ss" % int((time.time() - start_time)))
        time.sleep(2)
        element_by_id = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="product-transaction-area"]/div[3]/button')))
    except exp.NoSuchElementException as e:
        no_such_element_exption('In den Wb2', str(e))

try:
        print("ZK" + " - Time used=%ss" % int((time.time() - start_time)))
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        element_by_class = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'button-big')))
    except exp.NoSuchElementException as e:
        no_such_element_exption('ZK', str(e))
```

I prefer to execute this 2nd statement between 50-99 seconds, Can anyone please help to solve this issues

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me would to avoid using webdriverwait.

You can do some pooling:

```
   '''
driver.get('exammple.com')
found=False
while(not found):
   elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('example')
   if elem:
       found=True
found=False
while(not found):
   elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('example')
   if elem:
       found=True
'''
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work, the same problem repeated

Comment: u need to elaborate more informations, that would help to understand your problem, because saying that you want 50-99 seconds to execute it.